# Submit custom form in Magento 2.3 admin

Tags: magento2.3, custom, adminform, parameter, submit-form

I'm creating a custom form in Magento 2.3 admin.

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/route_folder_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\NewFunction\Edit" name="newfunction.form.container" template="newfunction.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/NewFunction/Edit.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Export edit block
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\NewFunction;

/**
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    public function getNewFunctionUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('route/folder/newfunction');
    }

}
```

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/newfunction.phtml

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getNewFunctionUrl()?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="hello"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

> Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Folder/NewFunction.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Folder;


class NewFunction extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function execute()
    {

        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    }
}
```

The form submits perfectly but when I debug the $params variable it shows only two parameters

```
key
adminhtml
```

I was expecting the **hello** text as one of the parameter but didn't
receive one on form submit.

Is there anything wrong with the process or code?

Comment: $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

Comment: getting blank array on running $this->getRequest()->getPostValue()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your controller should extend *Magento\Backend\App\Action*
and implements *Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface*,
also don't forget about ACL.

So should look something like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Folder;

class NewFunction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action implements \Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    public const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Cms::save';

    public function execute()
    {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        //OR
        $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('hello'); 
    }
}
```

Also don't forget about form_key input, your view should look like:

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getNewFunctionUrl()?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?= $block->getFormKey() ?>">
    <input type="text" name="hello"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: If I use \Magento\Backend\App\Action as extends class then form submission navigates me to dashboard

Comment: @RizwanDhuka sorry, I updated the answer. Please don't forget about form_key in .phtml

Comment: Thanks @underser it worked!

Comment: yep i was missing <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?= $block->getFormKey() ?>">

Answer (score 0):

You need to try code like this one.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Folder;

class NewFunction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        //OR
        $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('hello'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: on executing this $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams(); I'm getting only two parameters as mentioned in the question and on executing this $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('hello'); I'm getting NULL

Comment: Have you implement above code and run the caching command? remember you change extends class same as above I mension.

Comment: If I use \Magento\Backend\App\Action as extends class then form submission navigates me to dashboard.

Comment: after above change run the caching command and then check.